# React: Using document.QuerySelector as part of a library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, selector, gsap

I am trying to use an image hover effect library in React. [Here is the library](https://github.com/robin-dela/hover-effect). The library uses Three.js and GSAP to animate images. I've built a small example project with this library in a vanilla JS file.

I was able to build it easily like this. Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"/>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="distortion">
      </div>
      <div class="distortion2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js" integrity="sha256-lPE3wjN2a7ABWHbGz7+MKBJaykyzqCbU96BJWjio86U=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.min.js" integrity="sha256-3mBEX8I0uMLF7+AUjJeTCelosuorzYpqwBMBPDTyQqY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./hover.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS file:

```
new hoverEffect({
  parent: document.querySelector(".distortion"),
  intensity: 1,
  image1: "./images/kaapo.jpg",
  image2: "./images/kakko-rangers.jpg",
  displacementImage: "./images/ladyliberty3.png"
});


new hoverEffect({
  parent: document.querySelector(".distortion2"),
  intensity: 1,
  image1: "./images/jack.jpg",
  image2: "./images/hughes-card.jpg",
  displacementImage: "./images/devils-40.png"
});
```

Everything works, but now I'm trying to do something similar in a React project and I'm having trouble using this library in React.

Here is what I've tried:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import hoverEffect from 'hover-effect';
import kakko from '../assets/kaapo.jpg';
import {kakkoRangers} from '../assets/kakko-rangers.jpg';
import {ladyLiberty} from '../assets/ladyliberty3.png';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const STYLES = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

  .my-div {
    height: 20em;
    width: 30em;
  }
`;

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
  }

  render() {
    const animation = new hoverEffect({
          parent: document.querySelector('.my-div'),
          intensity: 0.3,
          image1: {kakko},
          image2: {kakkoRangers},
          displacementImage: {ladyLiberty}
      });

    return (
      <STYLES>
        <div>
          <h1>Test</h1>
          <div className="my-div">
          </div>
        </div>
      </STYLES>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

I don't think `document.querySelector('.my-div')` is working in my animation variable. Do querySelectors not work in React? How can I properly select the div?

How could I implement this in React? I tried nesting the animation variable in componentDidMount but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you want to directly access DOM elements in React you use the `ref` keyword:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

More at the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs).

Comment: How would I use this in conjunction with a library that expects the ref passed in as it's parent property in the hoverEffect function?